# trying to get the left outer join with linq expresssion using multiple tables in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am trying to get the result set from left outer join using linq. Below is my sql statement

```
select
    cra.room_number,HERS_SCHEDULE_ID,hs.HES_AVAILABLE_DATE,USERS.USER_FNAME
from coded_room cra
left outer join HE_REGULAR_SCHEDULE hrs 
    on  cra.room_number = hrs.hers_room_number
left outer join HE_SCHEDULE hs 
    on hs.HES_SCHEDULE_ID= hrs.HERS_SCHEDULE_ID
left outer join USERS 
    on hs.HES_HE_ID = USERS.USER_ID
where cra.ROOM_borough_id = 3
```

Output

```
room_number HERS_SCHEDULE_ID    HES_AVAILABLE_DATE         USER_FNAME
 1          285                 2015-09-18 00:00:00.000    john
 2          287                 2015-09-18 00:00:00.000    david
 3          NULL                NULL                       NULL
```

What I tried using Linq

```
from  coded_room cr in Context.coded_room
join hereg in Context.HE_REGULAR_SCHEDULE on cr.room_number equals hereg.HERS_ROOM_NUMBER   into leftjoin1
from x in   leftjoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join he in Context.HE_SCHEDULE on x.HERS_SCHEDULE_ID  equals he.HES_SCHEDULE_ID into leftjoin2
from y in leftjoin2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join userlinq in Context.USERS on y.USERS.USER_ID equals  userlinq.USER_ID  into leftjoin3
from z in leftjoin3.DefaultIfEmpty()
where cr.ROOM_borough_id == borough && y.HES_AVAILABLE_DATE == d                                   
select new HE_SCHEDULEDTO { RoomNumber = cr.room_id,UserName = z.USER_LNAME};
```

Output of my Linq

```
room_number HERS_SCHEDULE_ID    HES_AVAILABLE_DATE        USER_FNAME
  1                285          2015-09-18 00:00:00.000   john
  2                287          2015-09-18 00:00:00.000   david
```

What I want?

I want some pointers to modify the above linq query to give the output. Please see sql query above for reference

```
 room_number    HERS_SCHEDULE_ID    HES_AVAILABLE_DATE         USER_FNAME
 1              285                 2015-09-18 00:00:00.000    john
 2              287                 2015-09-18 00:00:00.000    david
 3              NULL                NULL                       NULL
```

Comment: `y.HES_AVAILABLE_DATE == d` In this line you are carrying date. To my guess you must be carrying current date as a filter in **Where** clause. Now a date can't be equals to **null** so either it will be a **MinDate** , **Maxdate** or simple a **Date** therefore you didn't got the third row as **null**.

Answer (score 0):

Your provided date clause excludes the room 3 row because there is a null date value. Run below to confirm:

```
where cr.ROOM_borough_id == borough
```